# Why a class is not being loaded correctly in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

In my application Im using React on Rails and webpack to build it.

Im using OSX with VSCode. When I try to import my Redux Store from my file Im getting a weird "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../bundles/store".

But on the next line, same file, the import is being made correctly.

This is my client/app/components/wallbuilder/wallbuilder.jsx imports:

```
import { store as STORE } from "../../bundles/store";
import { enclosure } from "../../bundles/store/action_creators.jsx";
```

And here my client/app/bundles/store.jsx file:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';

// Note: this file is not very decomposed on purpose.
// Start splitting only if this is unwieldy to handle

function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}
// Enclosure
import * as ACTIONS from './store/actions.jsx';
const ENCLOSURE_INITIAL = {cladding: '', type: '', showFilters: true};

function enclosure(state = ENCLOSURE_INITIAL, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case ACTIONS.ENCLOSURE_SET_CLADDING:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {cladding: action.value})
  case ACTIONS.ENCLOSURE_SET_TYPE:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {type: action.value})
  case ACTIONS.ENCLOSURE_SHOW_FILTERS:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {showFilters: action.value})
  default:
    return state;
  }

}



export const store = createStore(combineReducers({counter, enclosure}));
```

This line that try to import {store as STORE } is the one being broken.

On my Folder/Files I have.

So, what are the options for the store not being correctly loaded on my wallbuilder file?

Comment: `store.jsx` has `import` below the `counter` reducer. [It should be on the top of the file](https://medium.com/@jakewies/you-must-import-all-es6-modules-at-the-top-level-of-your-javascript-files-67888dfad66). Would moving the `import` to the top help the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making small mistake here. JSX is an extension of react jsx syntax but your code is just js code so you need to change file extension to js like this

```
import { enclosure } from "../../bundles/store/action_creators.js";
```

Comment: I moved all my files to the same folder and it worked. I think is something related to the import "../../|